# Zoom to polygon's extent in OpenLayers

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers

I've an array of coordinates that represent a polygon, inspired from this official example I've modified *"Fly to Bern"* for my aims.

```
<button id="testID">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

var polygon = [
    [
        13.147888181763385,
        38.696496657431524
    ],
    [
        13.147888181763385,
        38.711500431313084
    ],
    [
        13.16196441467133,
        38.72248334089265
    ],
    [
        13.185997007441344,
        38.7267688965631
    ],
    [
        13.204193113396066,
        38.71069673752169
    ],
    [
        13.197326658318405,
        38.698104355211626
    ],
    [
        13.183593748163982,
        38.68470576954256
    ],
    [
        13.153381345825155,
        38.68470576954256
    ],
    [
        13.151321409301318,
        38.688993589981564
    ],
    [
        13.147888181763385,
        38.696496657431524
    ]
];
var boundaryBox = new ol.extent.boundingExtent(polygon);
console.log(boundaryBox);

function onClick(id, callback) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', callback);
};

function flyTo(location, done) {
  var duration = 2000;
  var zoom = 5;
  var parts = 2;
  var called = false;
  function callback(complete) {
    --parts;
    if (called) {
      return;
    }
    if (parts === 0 || !complete) {
      called = true;
      done(complete);
    }
  }
  view.animate({
    center: boundaryBox,
    duration: duration
  }, callback);
  view.animate({
    zoom: zoom - 1,
    duration: duration / 2
  }, {
    zoom: zoom,
    duration: duration / 2
  }, callback);
};

onClick('testID', function() {
  flyTo(boundaryBox, function() {});
});

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
</script>
```

When I click on the button happen that the zoom is on coordinates "0.0, 0.0" instead of the boundary box's coordinates and there aren't errors in console. Probably I've misunderstand something, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above cannot work at all since view is not defined as separate object as it should be:

```
var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
  zoom: 4
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: view
});
```

Also `center` option in `view.animate` setting should be `flyTo` function parameter `location`:

```
view.animate({
  center: location,
  duration: duration
}, callback);
```

Now code indeed behaves as described. Reason for this is that extent is in `EPSG:4326`, while the view is standard `EPSG:3857`. What is needed is simple extent transform:

```
var boundaryBox = ol.proj.transformExtent(new ol.extent.boundingExtent(polygon), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```